# How to show / get only two numbers Date of current day date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, datetime

I want to know how i can  show or get only two numbers Date of current day date in **Javascript**,

So i can make same if else statements in javascript,  for example like this in **php**

```
$dt = date("d");

 if ( $dt < 10) {then do this} or  if ( $dt > 20) {then do this.}
```

in **php** i get this 2 numbers current date with this simple command

```
echo date("d");
```

Anyone help me out how i can get this in **javascript.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest you could do is to use [Date.prototype.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) :

```js
const d = new Date().getDate();

if (d <= 10) { 
  console.log(`Date is: ${d}. Do this`);
} else if (d >= 20) {
  console.log(`Date is: ${d}. Do something else`);
}
```

Or you could opt for using date libraries like [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns), [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) or any other - for better timezone handling.